# Building LLVM pass out of source - undefined symbols

Tags: cmake, llvm

I'm attempting to build an LLVM pass using the instructions [here](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html) and link it against the copy of LLVM installed by Julia. The pass is currently being compiled successfully, but cmake fails on linking with undefined symbol errors.

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object VectorizePass/CMakeFiles/VectorizePass.dir/VectorizePass.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared module libVectorizePass.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "llvm::raw_ostream::write_escaped(llvm::StringRef, bool)", referenced from:
  (anonymous namespace)::Hello::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) in VectorizePass.cpp.o
   "llvm::raw_ostream::write(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
        llvm::raw_ostream::operator<<(llvm::StringRef) in VectorizePass.cpp.o
```

There are dozens of undefined symbol errors followed by

```
"vtable for llvm::Pass", referenced from:
  llvm::Pass::Pass(llvm::PassKind, char&) in VectorizePass.cpp.o
NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual 
    member function has no definition.
```

**VectorizePass.cpp**

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"


using namespace llvm;

namespace {
    struct Hello : public FunctionPass {
        static char ID;
        Hello() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

        bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
            errs() << "Hello: ";
            errs().write_escaped(F.getName()) << "\n";
            return false;
        }
    };
}

char Hello::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<Hello> X("Hello",  "My Hello World Pass",  false, false);
```

This is exactly as it is in the tutorial.

**CMakeLists.txt (1)**

```
add_library(VectorizePass MODULE VectorizePass.cpp)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -Wall -fno-rtti -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -fPIC")
```

**CMakeLists.txt (2)**

```
project(VectorizePass)

set(LLVM_DIR "/Users/user/julia5/deps/build/llvm-3.7.1/build_Release")
set(LLVM_TOOLS_BINARY_DIR "/Users/user/julia5/deps/build/llvm-3.7.1/build_Release/Release/bin")

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories("/Users/user/julia5/deps/build/llvm-3.7.1/build_Release/include")
include_directories("/Users/user/julia5/deps/srccache/llvm-3.7.1/include")
link_directories("/Users/user/julia5/deps/build/llvm-3.7.1/build_Release/Release/lib")
link_directories("/Users/user/julia5/deps/build/llvm-3.7.1/build_Release/lib")
link_directories(${LLVM_LINK_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})


add_subdirectory(VectorizePass)
```

Clearly, for some reason CMake isn't finding the appropriate object files even though they *are* in the directories that I have in the `link_directories` statements. What am I missing? I'm fairly new to CMake so it may be something obvious.

I've attempted to `include(AddLLVM)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863706/llvm-out-of-source-pass-build-loadable-modules-not-supported-on-linux) but CMake reports that it cannot find `AddLLVM`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193757/issues-running-a-simple-out-of-source-llvm-pass) Stack post also suggests using a regular Makefile but that does not work when compiling out-of-source passes as all the paths in the regular LLVM `Makefile.common`/`Makefile.config` are relative and don't work at all.

Comment: `for some reason CMake isn't finding the appropriate object files even though they are in the directories that I have in the link_directories statements.` - You need to specify which object files (**libraries**) you need with [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) command.

Comment: Can you check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37308946/4946286

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#cmake-out-of-source-pass)? You need to use `add_llvm_loadable_module()` macro to define target for your pass.

Comment: As stated in my question, `include(AddLLVM)` and the other code from my section will not compile - CMake reports that `AddLLVM` could not be found. Also, if you read the link that you provided (and that is also linked in my answer), `add_llvm_loadable_module()` is optional and suggested only if you wish to merge the pass into the LLVM source tree at some point.

Comment: I, initially, wrote that section. You'd better find out why CMake gives you that error. You, probably, need to point it to LLVM CMake modules with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or something like that. Anyway, you can just use `add_llvm_loadable_module()` as reference to see how to set up CMakeLists.txt.